# MySQL InnoDB compression of INTEGER and DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, integer, compression, innodb

Reading the article [How Compression Works for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-internals.html) article I only find examples with data types like `BLOB`, `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`. Of course compression works best for these since you often have repeating patterns (at least for the character based types).

But how does it look for number or date columns (in my case `INT` and `DATETIME`)?
Can these types be compressed as well and what would be the best `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE`?

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
pk (INT) | account_id (INT) | time (DATETIME)
---------+------------------+--------------------
       1 |                1 | 2015/09/29 12:00:01
       2 |                1 | 2015/09/29 12:00:05
       3 |                2 | 2015/09/29 12:03:12
       4 |                2 | 2015/09/29 13:49:34
       5 |                4 | 2015/09/29 13:37:42
```

Answer (score 1):

No, these are fields that you probably want to use to narrow down query results and should not be compressed. The fields that you want to compress are blobs, varchars, text... fields that are rather large and something you are not filtering on.